# ValueError: unsupported format character 'C' (0x43)

Tags: python, web, unicode, encoding, runtime-error

I'm getting this error on creating a string with arguments like `"abcd%s"%(e)` but I'm getting e by scraping a web page. Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to avoid this error.

I found other similar questions but they were using `%20` in the url for which they need to replace `%20` with `%%20` which solved their problem. But my case is different. I tried encoding e but still getting same error.

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'W' (0x57)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and the original string please? You do have something with the format `%ddW` with `dd` being a number of digits, it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> "abcd%W"%(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character 'W' (0x57) at index 5
```

Could something like this work for you instead?

```
>>> "abcd%W".replace('%W', str(123))
'abcd123'
```